# How to force Android ListView NOT to update while scrolling?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, reload

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter, and an animation in `getView()` for each item. The point is, that I want to animate each item once, but it happens every time an item appears on screen (I scroll down, more items appear with animation, but when I scroll back, it happens to items I've seen earlier).

I wonder if there is an method to kill ListView update? It's the more annoying because it also reloads images that I get from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The point is, that i want to animate each item once, but it happens every time an item appears on screen

Then keep track of which ones you have animated before and don't animate them again.

> I wonder if there is an method to kill ListView update?

No.

> It's the more annoying cause it also reloads images that i get from the web.

Cache those images, to memory and/or to disk, so the images are not downloaded multiple times.

Comment: 1 - i tried to do that but for some reason some items got animated twice, then no more; 2 - ok, good to know; 3 - will try